# For each array call function to print python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to loop through this JSON response and send each array individually to another function for printing.

```
json_list = { 
"value":  [
 {
"name": "placeHolder",
"section": "right"
  },
{
"name": "Overview",
"section": "left"
}, 
{
"name": "ByFunction",
"section": "left"
}, 
{
"name": "Time",
"section": "left"
 },
 {
"name": "allFit",
"section": "left"
}
]
}
```

Below is the code I am using. I am looping through the list and picking the keys and values and pair them, then send to the print function. But it's only printing the first JSON array. I want to print all of them individually as a JSON string.

```
 objects_list = []
 for data in json_list['value']:
     d = collections.OrderedDict()
     d['name'] = data['name']
     d['section'] = data['section']
  objects_list.append(d)
  get_print(objects_list)         

 def get_print(data):
     for dt in data:
        name= dt['name'],
        section= dt['section'], 
      print(name)
      print(section)
```

Comment: Is your code written correctly? Your function definition is down and your code is above. What does your function do? Do you want to print the objects?

Comment: Hi JoeFerndz thank you for your response, i want to print the objects, what my function is doing is getting the object and print each array string in the object but its only print one array string from the object

Comment: see if my response helped you. If not, we can work to address your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

In the first example, I am using the json_list as is.

```
json_list = { 
"value":  [
 {
"name": "placeHolder",
"section": "right"
  },
{
"name": "Overview",
"section": "left"
}, 
{
"name": "ByFunction",
"section": "left"
}, 
{
"name": "Time",
"section": "left"
 },
 {
"name": "allFit",
"section": "left"
}
]
}
```

## without json.loads

```
value_list = json_list['value']
for k in value_list:
    print (k['name'],k['section'])
```

## with json.loads

In this example, I am converting the entire json list as a string.

```
import json
json_list = '{"value":[{"name": "placeHolder","section": "right"},{"name": "Overview","section": "left"},{"name": "ByFunction","section": "left"},{"name": "Time","section": "left"},{"name": "allFit","section": "left"}]}'

data  = json.loads(json_list)
value_list = data['value']

for k in value_list:
    print (k['name'],k['section'])
```

The output will be printed as:

```
placeHolder right
Overview left
ByFunction left
Time left
allFit left
```

## Save json to a list

If you want to save this to a list so it can be processed later, you can do the following:

```
name = []
section = []

value_list = json_list['value']
for k in value_list:
    name.append(k['name'])
    section.append(k['section'])

print (name)
print (section)
```

The output will be as follows:

```
['placeHolder', 'Overview', 'ByFunction', 'Time', 'allFit']

['right', 'left', 'left', 'left', 'left']
```

Comment: Hi, yes so if i want to  append the results to a list and send the list as an object for each iteration....?

Comment: @mrmubanga  see the updated response. Maybe this is what you are looking for?

Comment: @mrmubanga, if the response provided you what you were looking for, please upvote the answer.